# Using Visual Studio 2017/2019 to run VS 2008 C++ project

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I wonder if anybody has experience converting VS 2008 C++ solution to VS 2017/19 without switching to newer SDK and toolset. The solution is quite old, very large, uses 3-rd party libraries, so full conversion is out of the question. The goal is only to switch to better user interface.

Theoretically it is *probably* possible, although I successfully converted only very basic C++ MFC project.

Project settings in VS 2017 show only latest toolset. To make other toolsets to appear, I had to install VS 2010, and also add SDK 8.1 from VS installer (without VS 2010, this option is not available). Then select toolset v.90 and SDK 8.1 for each project in solution.

At this point, simple converted project works fine. A large legacy solution has a lots of issues. I resolved generic ones, but it looks like uphill battle. For example, C++ directories are physically different and some of the files are missing. It may be possible to eventually assign original VS 2008 directories to each project and/or copy missing files, but I have the impression of doing something illegal.

The question is, is it a valid procedure and still possible after latest updates.
Thanks==

Comment: I did something similar ages ago. It was about 500 cpp and h files. My method was to just recreate the solution and add the files. Trying to convert it was too messy. Took the opportunity to upgrade all of the dependencies too.

Comment: You can install the VS2008 tooset to recent versions of Visual Stuido. Here is the link to the documentation: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/use-native-multi-targeting?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/use-native-multi-targeting?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy way. If your legacy project is based on an older version of Visual Studio, you can open it in Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio 2019. Visual Studio automatically converts it to the current project schema with support for all the latest compiler and IDE features. However, there will be a series of errors that you need to solve. You could refer to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/ide-tools-for-upgrading-code?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Microsoft spec was working for a very simple case only. The solution has 75 projects, over 750 C/C++ and 900 header files, but the most problematic are some invasive proprietary and 3-rd party libraries (like Boost). Replacing them with newer versions not always possible and debugging is out of the question. Looks like this task is error-prone and maybe impossible. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I managed to resolve all missing header issues by adding in Visual Studio Installer to "Compilers, build tools, and runtimes" a component "VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop".  Now everything builds and one of the subprojects runs correctly.

Comment: Of course, there are new warnings to address or to disable, and some of the projects had ancient WINVER parameters, not supported any more. Theoretically, SDK 8.1 should allow linking with DLLs, built with Visual Studio 2008.